# Formatear fecha en formato día, mes, año y hora

Tags: php

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
<br><br><br><br><br>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                        <h1 class="text-warning mt-4 mb-4">
                            <b><span id="average_rating">0.0</span> / 5</b>
                        </h1>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                        </div>
                        <h3><span id="total_review">0</span> Revisar</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <p>
                            <div class="progress-label-left"><b>5</b> <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i></div>

                            <div class="progress-label-right">(<span id="total_five_star_review">0</span>)</div>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="five_star_progress"></div>
                            </div>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <div class="progress-label-left"><b>4</b> <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i></div>
                            
                            <div class="progress-label-right">(<span id="total_four_star_review">0</span>)</div>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="four_star_progress"></div>
                            </div>               
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <div class="progress-label-left"><b>3</b> <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i></div>
                            
                            <div class="progress-label-right">(<span id="total_three_star_review">0</span>)</div>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="three_star_progress"></div>
                            </div>               
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <div class="progress-label-left"><b>2</b> <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i></div>
                            
                            <div class="progress-label-right">(<span id="total_two_star_review">0</span>)</div>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="two_star_progress"></div>
                            </div>               
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <div class="progress-label-left"><b>1</b> <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i></div>
                            
                            <div class="progress-label-right">(<span id="total_one_star_review">0</span>)</div>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="one_star_progress"></div>
                            </div>               
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                        <h3 class="mt-4 mb-3">Escribe una reseña aquí</h3>
                        <button type="button" name="add_review" id="add_review" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-5" id="review_content"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<div id="review_modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Enviar opinión</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 class="text-center mt-2 mb-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-star star-light submit_star mr-1" id="submit_star_1" data-rating="1"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star star-light submit_star mr-1" id="submit_star_2" data-rating="2"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star star-light submit_star mr-1" id="submit_star_3" data-rating="3"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star star-light submit_star mr-1" id="submit_star_4" data-rating="4"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star star-light submit_star mr-1" id="submit_star_5" data-rating="5"></i>
                </h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduzca su nombre" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="user_review" id="user_review" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba su reseña aquí"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center mt-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save_review">Enviar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.progress-label-left
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.progress-label-right
{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.star-light
{
    color:#e9ecef;
}
</style>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var rating_data = 0;

    $('#add_review').click(function(){

        $('#review_modal').modal('show');

    });

    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.submit_star', function(){

        var rating = $(this).data('rating');

        reset_background();

        for(var count = 1; count <= rating; count++)
        {

            $('#submit_star_'+count).addClass('text-warning');

        }

    });

    function reset_background()
    {
        for(var count = 1; count <= 5; count++)
        {

            $('#submit_star_'+count).addClass('star-light');

            $('#submit_star_'+count).removeClass('text-warning');

        }
    }

    $(document).on('mouseleave', '.submit_star', function(){

        reset_background();

        for(var count = 1; count <= rating_data; count++)
        {

            $('#submit_star_'+count).removeClass('star-light');

            $('#submit_star_'+count).addClass('text-warning');
        }

    });

    $(document).on('click', '.submit_star', function(){

        rating_data = $(this).data('rating');

    });

    $('#save_review').click(function(){

        var user_name = $('#user_name').val();

        var user_review = $('#user_review').val();

        if(user_name == '' || user_review == '')
        {
            alert("Complete ambos campos");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"submit_rating.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{rating_data:rating_data, user_name:user_name, user_review:user_review},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#review_modal').modal('hide');

                    load_rating_data();

                    alert(data);
                }
            })
        }

    });

    load_rating_data();

    function load_rating_data()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"submit_rating.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:'load_data'},
            dataType:"JSON",
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#average_rating').text(data.average_rating);
                $('#total_review').text(data.total_review);

                var count_star = 0;

                $('.main_star').each(function(){
                    count_star++;
                    if(Math.ceil(data.average_rating) >= count_star)
                    {
                        $(this).addClass('text-warning');
                        $(this).addClass('star-light');
                    }
                });

                $('#total_five_star_review').text(data.five_star_review);

                $('#total_four_star_review').text(data.four_star_review);

                $('#total_three_star_review').text(data.three_star_review);

                $('#total_two_star_review').text(data.two_star_review);

                $('#total_one_star_review').text(data.one_star_review);

                $('#five_star_progress').css('width', (data.five_star_review/data.total_review) * 100 + '%');

                $('#four_star_progress').css('width', (data.four_star_review/data.total_review) * 100 + '%');

                $('#three_star_progress').css('width', (data.three_star_review/data.total_review) * 100 + '%');

                $('#two_star_progress').css('width', (data.two_star_review/data.total_review) * 100 + '%');

                $('#one_star_progress').css('width', (data.one_star_review/data.total_review) * 100 + '%');

                if(data.review_data.length > 0)
                {
                    var html = '';

                    for(var count = 0; count < data.review_data.length; count++)
                    {
                        html += '<div class="row mb-3">';

                        html += '<div class="col-sm-1"><div class="rounded-circle bg-danger text-white pt-2 pb-2"><h3 class="text-center">'+data.review_data[count].user_name.charAt(0)+'</h3></div></div>';

                        html += '<div class="col-sm-11">';

                        html += '<div class="card">';

                        html += '<div class="card-header"><b>'+data.review_data[count].user_name+'</b></div>';

                        html += '<div class="card-body">';

                        for(var star = 1; star <= 5; star++)
                        {
                            var class_name = '';

                            if(data.review_data[count].rating >= star)
                            {
                                class_name = 'text-warning';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                class_name = 'star-light';
                            }

                            html += '<i class="fas fa-star '+class_name+' mr-1"></i>';
                        }

                        html += '<br />';

                        html += data.review_data[count].user_review;

                        html += '</div>';

                        html += '<div class="card-footer text-right">On '+data.review_data[count].datetime+'</div>';

                        html += '</div>';

                        html += '</div>';

                        html += '</div>';
                    }

                    $('#review_content').html(html);
                }
            }
        })
    }

});

</script>
```

Estoy haciendo una página de reseñas y calificaciones, entonces mi código me arroja la fecha en inglés. He escuchado que debo poner el "setlocale" pero ya he intentado y no sé cómo hacerlo funcionar.

Quiero que al poner una calificación y la envíen me salga la fecha en español como día, mes, año y hora.

Anexo mi php donde está la mayoría de la información

```
    <?php

    //submit_rating.php

    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mt", "root", "");



    if(isset($_POST["rating_data"]))
    {

        $data = array(
            ':user_name'        =>  $_POST["user_name"],
            ':user_rating'      =>  $_POST["rating_data"],
            ':user_review'      =>  $_POST["user_review"],
            ':datetime'         =>  time()
        );

        $query = "
        INSERT INTO review_table 
        (user_name, user_rating, user_review, datetime  ) 
        VALUES (:user_name, :user_rating, :user_review, :datetime  )
        ";
        
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

        $statement->execute($data);

        echo "Su revisión y calificación se enviaron con éxito";

    }

    if(isset($_POST["action"]))
    {
        $average_rating = 0;
        $total_review = 0;
        $five_star_review = 0;
        $four_star_review = 0;
        $three_star_review = 0;
        $two_star_review = 0;
        $one_star_review = 0;
        $total_user_rating = 0;
        $review_content = array();

        $query = "
        SELECT * FROM review_table 
        ORDER BY review_id DESC
        ";

        $result = $connect->query($query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $review_content[] = array(
                'user_name'     =>  $row["user_name"],
                'user_review'   =>  $row["user_review"],
                'rating'        =>  $row["user_rating"],
                'datetime'      =>  date('l jS, F Y h:i:s A', $row["datetime"])
            );

            if($row["user_rating"] == '5')
            {
                $five_star_review++;
            }

            if($row["user_rating"] == '4')
            {
                $four_star_review++;
            }

            if($row["user_rating"] == '3')
            {
                $three_star_review++;
            }

            if($row["user_rating"] == '2')
            {
                $two_star_review++;
            }

            if($row["user_rating"] == '1')
            {
                $one_star_review++;
            }

            $total_review++;

            $total_user_rating = $total_user_rating + $row["user_rating"];

        }

        $average_rating = $total_user_rating / $total_review;

        $output = array(
            'average_rating'    =>  number_format($average_rating, 1),
            'total_review'      =>  $total_review,
            'five_star_review'  =>  $five_star_review,
            'four_star_review'  =>  $four_star_review,
            'three_star_review' =>  $three_star_review,
            'two_star_review'   =>  $two_star_review,
            'one_star_review'   =>  $one_star_review,
            'review_data'       =>  $review_content
        );

        echo json_encode($output);

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Quieres que "Me salga" la fecha con formato en dónde? El script que muestras tiene unas consultas PHP y pues... si estás guardando la fecha en un campo de fecha, es suficiente. Para _pintar_ una fecha con un formato específico, depende de **dónde* lo estás pintando; si consultas el dato de la BD, te entrega un valor que puedes formatear como gustes... pero no sabemos dónde lo estás pintando

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Hola si gracias, te explico hice una pagina donde mandas reseñas de esa pagina pero al imprimir los datos en pantalla la fecha de el comentario me sale en ingles y quiero que salga en español

Comment: ENtonces hay que ver el código de la página que imprime los datos y/o datos de prueba en tu tabla de comentarios :)

Comment: Ya subi todo mi codifo